# Is it mandatory to give '\0' for initialization of character arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings

Please see the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[10] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'}; // did not add `\0`
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        c = name[i];
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I did not give `\0` at the end, but still it works.

My question:  Is `\0` added automatically in the above case?

**EDIT**: What happens in these cases:

1. `char name[7] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`
2. `char name[8] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`

I apologize for editing the question.

Comment: You can write `char name[10] = "Lessons";` for the same effect. Or `char name[] = "Lessons";` to let the compiler automatically select the size `8`, based on the size of the initializer.

Comment: Please don't edit a question in a way that substantially invalidates answers already given.

Comment: *"but still it works"* - don't confuse observed behavior with defined behavior. You have a 7-char character array with 7 non-nulchar entries. By definition you have to breach your declared limit to find a nulchar, which invokes *undefined behavior*. Whether it appears to "work" or not is irrelevant (and simultaneously, unfortunate, as a hard crash and burn would have been far more illuminating to the bug in your code).

Comment: Sorry for editing the question. I forgot to change the value.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Maybe you can add the case of the `[7]` array as a footnote or other 'addition' to your question. But please **don't** make edits that invalidate already-posted answers.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula, perhaps you do not appreciate that it is in fact a completely different question when the array is dimensioned for 10 `char`s than when it is dimensioned for 7.

Comment: @AdrianMole  I edited the question. I hope this is fine.

Comment: Note that this has been a chameleon question — the length of the main array was initially 10, then 7, and it has been changed and augmented several times since then. Some of the comments above address intermediate states of the question. @Krishna: please don't change the substance of a question once you've gotten any answers — it isn't fair to those answering. It isn't a particularly good idea to make substantive changes once you get comments, either. It can be OK to add to a question (the alternative arrays with sizes 7 and 8 were mostly legitimate), but you must think carefully when asking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   Chux answered the question, by quoting that part of the question. I mean "EDIT : ....."  this part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, partially initialized arrays of **any** type are 0-initialized for the rest. So,

```c
int foo[5] = {1, 2, 3};
```

will initialize `foo` with `{1, 2, 3, 0, 0}`. So, when you don't add `'\0'` to the end, not only will the end be `'\0'` (assuming the array is large enough to fit it), but all remaining elements of the array will be `'\0'`.

If your array isn't large enough to fit the null terminator, then it won't be added, **nor should the value even matter**. Reading past the end of an array is undefined behavior, which can lead to segfaults, garbage data, or worse.

Comment: What if I give `char name[7] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`

Comment: Then reading past the end is undefined behavior and you should not rely on a specific value being at the end, nor should you even read past the end in the first place.

Comment: Is `\0` added automatically in this case ?

Comment: No, it is not. You don't allocate enough memory for the null byte, so it will not be added. As I said, you shouldn't even be reading the value after the array, as it could lead to segfaults, garbage data, or worse.

Comment: Sorry, deleted comment cause someone reverted the change, but the reversion got deleted. I know the answer. I thought maybe you could cover both cases.

Comment: @ikegami Regardless, I think the first 4 comments to this answer cover the case of an array with no partial initialization.

Comment: I am sorry for editing the question. I removed the edits, and added them at the end

Answer (score 4):

> *Is \0 added automatically in the above case?*

Yes. In fact, in your *first* case (where the array length is specified as 10), all three array elements that you have not *explicitly* initialized will be default initialized to zero.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization):

> All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are
> zero-initialized.

Or, from [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> ...
> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an
> aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize
> an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the
> remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as
> objects that have static storage duration.

---

The above is also true for the case in which you have declared `char name[8]` (but there will only be *one* added `'\0'`, in that case).

However, for the case of `char name[7] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`, then you have **undefined behaviour** - the value of the byte at the memory location immediately following your array could be anything (including zero).

Comment: @nanofarad I have rolled back the edit, as there were already two answers to the *original* question.

Comment: I am sorry for editing the question. I removed the edits, and added them at the end.

Comment: @AdrianMole The answer to the `char name[] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};` case would probably be the most illuminating - I don't have time right now to dig through the standard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That code would have the exact same effect as having the `7` between the square brackets.

Comment: That page from cppreference.com is wrong, and so is this answer in that regard. Aggregates with automatic storage duration and no explicit initializer(s) are not initialized. Elements without corresponding initializers are initialized only if there is at least one initializer. C 2018 6.7.9 10.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it mandatory to give '\0' for initialization of character arrays?

No, it is not.

On one hand, it is perfectly valid for an array of `char` or any other character type not to contain any element with value 0.  However, **such an array does not contain a string**, and passing a pointer (in)to it to any function relying on you to pass a string results in undefined behavior.  That may sometimes manifest as if the array were terminated, but it is not safe to assume that it will do so.

On the other hand, if you declare an array with an initializer that explicitly initializes only some of its elements, then the other elements are implicitly initialized.  For elements of type `char`, that takes the form of initialization to 0.  Note well that this behavior is associated with initializers, not assignment.

As applied to your code, then, when array `name` is declared with dimension 10 and the initializer provides only seven elements, the last three elements take the initial value zero.  It is equivalent to this:

```
    char name[10] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s', 0, 0, 0};
```

... or this:

```
    char name[10] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
```

... or even this:

```
    char name[10] = "Lessons";
```

... among other possibilities.

> **EDIT**: What happens in this cases :
>
> 1. `char name[7] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`

All array elements are explicitly initialized by the given initializer.  The array contents are not null-terminated, and thus do not constitute a string.  Undefined behavior results from any attempt to use them as if they were a string.

> 2. `char name[8] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`

One array element is not explicitly initialized, so it is implicitly initialized to 0.  If the intention is that `name` should have exactly the right number of elements to contain the specified characters plus a terminator, then that is more clearly and safely expressed as

```
char name[] = "Lessons"; // Array dimension computed automatically
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your answer.  Do we need to add `\0` in this case: `char name[] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`???

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula: in this example, `name` will have exactly 7 elements, without a null terminator. If you want to use `name` as a string, you need to write `char name[] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s',0};` or simply `char name[] = "Lessons";`

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula, a string literal includes a terminator (else it would not be a string).  When used as an initializer, therefore, that is included, contributing to the automatic array-length computation where relevant.  That is *not* the case, however, for the 7-character array-style initializer you present.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it mandatory to give `'\0'` for initialization of character arrays?

No, not in general.

Yet if code needs the initialized character array to be considered a *string*, then a *null character* is needed somehow: explicitly or implicitly.

---

```
char name[10] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};
```

> My question : Is `\0` added automatically in the above case?

Yes.  **There are no partial initializations**.  7 of the 10 elements are explicitly initialized.  If code only explicitly partially initializes an object,  "all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."  C17dr § 6.7.9 19

"If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
— **if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;**
— if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
— if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;  C17dr § 6.7.9 10

---

> EDIT: What happens in this cases :
> `char name[7] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`
> `char name[8] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`

`name[7]` is as coded.  No *null character* exist in `name[]` so the *character array* is *not* a *string*.

`name[8]` is as if `{'L','e','s','s','o','n','s', 0}` was coded.  Since it contains a  *null character*, `name[]` is also a *string*.

---

The below all initial `nameX[]` to the same value:

```
char name1[10] = {'L', 'e', 's', 's', 'o', 'n', 's'};
char name2[10] = {'L', 'e', 's', 's', 'o', 'n', 's', 0};
char name3[10] = {'L', 'e', 's', 's', 'o', 'n', 's', '\0'};
char name4[10] = {'L', 'e', 's', 's', 'o', 'n', 's', 0, 0, 0};
char name5[10] = {[0] = 'L', [1] = 'e', [2] = 's', [3] = 's', [4] = 'o', [5] = 'n', [6] = 's'};
char name6[10] = {[1] = 'e', [2] = 's', [3] = 's', [4] = 'o', [5] = 'n', [6] = 's', [0] = 'L'};
char name7[10] = {[1] = 'e', [3] = 's', [2] = name7[3], [4] = 'o', [5] = 'n', [6] = 's', [0] = 'L'};
char name8[10] = "Lessons";
char name9[10] = "Lessons\0";
```

Answer (score 1):

> I did not give \0 at the end, but still it works.

That's because you invoked undefined behavior.  On result of UB is that it appears to work properly.

You don't have to explicitly add the `'\0'` terminator **if you leave room for it**.

Your original code was

```
char name[7] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'}; // did not add `\0`
```

There's no room for a terminating `'\0'`.

Per [**6.7.9 Initialization**, paragraph 21 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21):

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Comment: I am sorry for editing the question. I removed the edits, and added them at the end

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula That's OK. The real interesting question is do you need to add a terminator if you write `char name[] = {'L','e','s','s','o','n','s'};`

Comment: The question got modified a _lot_ but the very [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65457697/1) had an array dimension of 10, which was subsequently changed to 7, and then other changes were made too.  That's nasty for anyone trying to answer.

Comment: @Jonathan  I removed the changes. And I added changes at the end. First version is still there, with some additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer of your question is yes. `'\0'` is added when your string(char array) ends.
If you don't want characters after some character then you can add `'\0'` explicitly after that character.

Comment: It partly depends on which version of the question you are looking at.  On the whole, while this answer is correct for the versions of the question with `char name[10] = …`, it doesn't provide enough details and caveats (or quotes of authoritative sources) to be a good answer.  It's particularly tough since the question changed multiple times.